# Macro to find paragraphs in text selection in Open/Libre/Neo Office

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, basic

I am trying to enumerate the paragraphs selected by the user in  (Neo|Libre|Open)Office.

When I use the code below, modified version from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice_Basic),

```
Sub CheckForSelection
    Dim oDoc as Object
    Dim oText

    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oText = oDoc.Text

    if not IsAnythingSelected(oDoc) then
        msgbox("No text selected!")
        Exit Sub
    end if

    oSelections = oDoc.getCurrentSelection() 
    oSel = oSelections.getByIndex(0)    

    ' Info box
    'MsgBox oSel.getString(), 64, "Your Selection"

    oPE = oSel.Text.createEnumeration()
    nPars = 0
    Do While oPE.hasMoreElements()
        oPar = oPE.nextElement()
        REM The returned paragraph will be a paragraph or a text table
        If oPar.supportsService("com.sun.star.text.Paragraph") Then 
            nPars = nPars + 1
        ElseIf oPar.supportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextTable") Then 
            nTables = nTables + 1
        end if
    Loop

    ' Info box
    MsgBox "You selection has " & nPars & " paragraphs.", 64

end Sub
```

it finds ALL the paragraphs in the document, not just in the selection. Google has failed me. Any thoughts on how to find individual paragraphs in the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `oSel.Text` is a shortcut for `oSel.getText()` which "Returns the text interface **in** which the text position is **contained**." https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextRange.html#getText

So to get a `ParagraphEnumeration` only from the `Selection`, you should use `oPE = oSel.createEnumeration()` instead of  `oPE = oSel.Text.createEnumeration()`.

Comment: I'll accept this since it did give the correct number of lines/paragraphs selected, although it returns the full paragraph even when part of it is selected. For my purposes that is good enough. Thx.